# How to keep rows in a DataFrame based on column unique sets?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How to keep rows in a DataFrame based on column unique pairs in Python?

I have a massive ocean datasets with over 300k rows. Given some unique latitude-longitude pairs have multiple depths, I am only interested in keeping unique rows that contain unique sets of Latitude-Longitude-Year-Month.

The goal here is to know how many months of sampling for a given Latitude-Longitude location.

I tried using pandas conditions but the sets that I want are dependent on each other.

Any ideas on how to do this?

So far I've tried the following:

```
# keep Latitude, Longitude, Year and Month
glp = glp[['latitude', 'longitude', 'year', 'month']]

# only keep unique rows
glp.drop_duplicates(keep = False, inplace = True)
```

but it removes too many lines as I want those four variables to work together

Comment: Hi.. Welcom to SO, please include what u have tried so far expected input & output. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you are looking for is .drop_duplicates()
Assuming your dataframe variable is df, you can use

```
df.drop_duplicates()
```

or include column name list if you're only looking for unique values within specified columns

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=[column_list])#column_list of names you want to compare
```

**Edit:**

If that's the case, I guess you could just do

```
df.groupby([column_list]).first() #first() takes the first values of other columns
```

And then you could just use df.reset_index() if you want the unique sets as columns again.

Comment: Thanks a ton for replying so fast! Unfortunately, drop_duplicates will only keep unique values within specified columns independent of each other. I want the rows with unique sets of Latitude Longitude Year Month - the rows are based on the dependence between these four!

Comment: Oops! My bad. Check out my edit and see if it's helpful

Comment: Hi! Turns out, drop_duplicates() will by default keep the first row of duplicates and keep:False will drop all duplicates. Thanks a ton for your help!